# Let $p$ be prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Find all roots of $x^p-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.  Find all roots of $x^p-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

I don't know where to start.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem comes to mind...

Comment: I guess my question is where to go from there. Is it since $a^p=a\mod(p)$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x^p-1$ becomes $x\mod(p)-1$? So the roots are $x-1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What happens if we expand $(x-1)^{p}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem says:

> If $p$ is a prime number, then $$a^p = a \pmod{p}$$

You are trying to solve:
$$x^p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
Then:
$$x^p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
By the FLT:...

Does that help?

Comment: That's really all there is to it?

Comment: So, $x=1$mod $p$. That's all. Which is just 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: That is it. ${}{}$

Comment: Perhaps one could add (as remarked in a comment to OP) that the root $1$ has multiplicity $p$, that is, $x^{p} - 1 = (x-1)^{p}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I don't entirely know what that means (I haven't reached that point in math), so I don't feel comfortable adding it myself (because I may inadvertently mess up the wording and change the meaning).  I do appreciate the suggestion, though.   (If you want to edit it in, or add an answer yourself, please feel free...) :)